# Retrieving Metabolic networks from WIT Database

Tags: networks, data-retrieval, public-dataset

How can I get the dataset for all the 43 metabolic networks for this paper:
https://www.nature.com/articles/35036627

It looks like the WIT database does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there are some files related to the databases at the ftp site: http://ftp.mcs.anl.gov/pub/WIT2/. The related files were last updated on 2002.

I found it via searching at google: `site:*.mcs.anl.gov/ WIT`.

Which reports also a [page](http://ftp.mcs.anl.gov/pub/tech_reports/reports/P694.html) about the database. There seems to be a project to develop WIT3, because there is a mailing list for [developers](https://lists.mcs.anl.gov/mailman/listinfo/wit3_development_team), maybe you can ask them more details if you have problems with the database.